# how to fill the paremeter into function name string for invoking?

Tags: python, string, parameters, eval, fill

I've got

```
str1 = 'foo1().foo2()'
para = [1,2]
```

what I want is:

```
str2 = "foo1(1).foo2(2)"
eval(str2)
```

and sort of:

```
eval(str1)(1,2)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: May I inquire as to why you're using `eval()` in the first place? It is typically a bad idea...

Comment: I have a plan to store the invoking chain (the function name with parameter) into a database for testing and audit purpose on my private app. when I need some of them later, I just using the sql command to get the line then paste it into the parser.

Comment: are your parameters always numbers? or strings?

Comment: string will be more suitable and flexible I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just store a [format string](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings), then?

```
str1 = 'foo1({0}).foo2({1})'
para = [1,2]
eval(str1.format(*para)) # equivalent to eval(str1.format(1,2))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, but this will bring another problem which is if I read 'foo1().foo2()' from file, I still need to put the {0} and {1} in whole string, that is same as to put the parameter in,  may I know anyother simple way to omitte the {0} and {1} before save/read the string to/from disk?

Comment: @user478514 If you're using python 3.1 or above (or 2.7), you don't have to number the fields in the format string. This may be too simple/naive (depending on what you're storing exactly), but you could just do something like `str1.replace('()', '({})')` and vice versa.